# Items hidding from users in sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, hide-elements

I need to hide Items from users in SharePoint list.  Users are able to submit items, but no one can able to see after item submitted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a workflow to copy the item to a different list, and then delete the original item. This is a pretty easy workflow to configure. You'd just need to create a new list with all the same fields etc. This is easily done if you used content types. If not, just save the list as a template (in the list settings screen), and then create a new list via that template.

Optionally, you could also create a workflow that modified the permissions of the current item, though this is quite a bit more difficult to configure.

Comment: Users need to see the link to the item, but not have access to actually read the item?

Comment: yes, and they want to look at the item by the link. If you copy and delete the item. They don't have access to look at

Comment: Look at what item by the link? You originally asked how to ensure users could see the item?

Comment: Yes, But they want to see there own item that submitted

Comment: You didn't specify that originally. To do that, just go to the advanced settings in the list, and change the settings in "item level permissions" as desired.